# JSON Array is not fetched in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, json

Am a begginer in Javascript and am trying to **Import data into Maps** , I have a **Json Array list** from my URL . but the Longitude and Latitude is not fetched and also i tried to print them in Console but nothing shows.

**This is my Json data :**

```
[{"Id":1,"Country":"Uganda","District":"kampala","SubCounty":"Hima","EpidemicName":"cholera","PatientName":"Michael","PatientResidenceArea":"Muhokya","Latitude":0.3249832,"Longitude":32.5753133,"HealthFacilityName":"Mulago","HealthOfficerName":"Fauziya"},{"Id":2,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Mbarara","SubCounty":"Mile","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":3,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Jinja","SubCounty":"kashaali","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":4,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Mbarara","SubCounty":"Mile","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":5,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Jinja","SubCounty":"kashaali","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":6,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Mbarara","SubCounty":"Mile","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":7,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Jinja","SubCounty":"kashaali","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":8,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Mbarara","SubCounty":"Mile","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":9,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Jinja","SubCounty":"kashaali","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":10,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Mbarara","SubCounty":"Mile","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"},{"Id":11,"Country":"Uganda","District":"Mbarara","SubCounty":"Mile","EpidemicName":"Cholera","PatientName":"Musa","PatientResidenceArea":"Kabalagala","Latitude":0.635364,"Longitude":0.354789,"HealthFacilityName":"Kiruddu","HealthOfficerName":"Mbabaali"}]
```

**And below is my code :**

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 2,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8, -187.3),
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            });

            // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
            // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
            script.src = 'http://localhost:82/Mobile/Fetch.aspx?DataFormat=Details';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }

        // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
        // set of coordinates.
        window.eqfeed_callback = function (results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
                var Ltd = results.Latitude[i];
                var Lgd = results.Longitude[i];
                console.log("Latitude : "+ Ltd+" Longitude : "+ Lgd);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Ltd, Lgd);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAYol0DZtLxlMaLW6S7QZIQk48Do18cm6A&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
```

**EDIT:**

**This is my update** 
But still don't know why its not bringing points even when i try to print the points they don't show in the console why?

```
var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 2,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8, -187.3),
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            });

            // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
            // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
            script.src = 'http://192.168.0.6:72/Mobile/Fetch.aspx?DataFormat=Details';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }

        // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
        // set of coordinates.
        window.eqfeed_callback = function (results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                var Ltd = results[i].Latitude;
                var Lgd = results[i].Longitude;
                console.log("Latitude : " + Ltd + " Longitude : " + Lgd);

                alert(""+ Ltd);
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Ltd, Lgd);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    label: results[i].EpidemicName
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.eqfeed_callback` function has some errors. It should look like this:

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function (results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var Ltd = results[i].Latitude;
        var Lgd = results[i].Longitude;
        console.log("Latitude : "+ Ltd+" Longitude : "+ Lgd);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Ltd, Lgd);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```

Notice that the `coords` variable has been removed because it is unused. Also, the array index must come after the name of the array, rather than at the end of the expression, such as in `var Ltd = results[i].Latitude;` rather than `var Ltd = results.Latitude[i];`

Also, the script loaded by the `initMap` function must call the `eqfeed_callback` function when it loads. This can be done by loading the JSON via jQuery, like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.0.6:72/Mobile/Fetch.aspx?DataForma‌​t=Details', eqfeed_callback);
```

**EDIT:**

To add a title to each marker, do something like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    label: results[i].EpidemicName
});
```

Please refer to the [Google Maps API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) for more information

Comment: what if , i want to **EpidemicName**, as my marker on each point what can i do. **EpidemicName** is also an Object in Json.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris I updated my answer with this information.

Comment: Thanks so much @Jason

Comment: @JasonSmith, how can i  load the `initMap`   function  which must call the `eqfeed_callback`  function when it loads.

Comment: @mswalehe `initMap` is already called when the Google Maps script loads. I edited my answer with information on how to call `eqfeed_callback` after your results load.

Comment: but still the map is not showing results, i changed my results, checkout my Edit in the post and see

Comment: but when i use this URL  http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp , i see it has `eqfeed_callback` , isn't that the problem , because me i dont need that since my json data doesn't have it

Comment: @mswalehe The script returned by `http://192.168.0.6:72/Mobile/Fetch.aspx?DataFormat=Details` must call `eqfeed_callback` with the JSON array as an argument. Otherwise, you need to use an AJAX library to load the data, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: So you mean i have to add `eqfeed_callback` inorder to fetch data like    `eqfeed_callback([{"Id":1,"Country":"Uganda","District":"kampala","SubCounty":"Hima","EpidemicName":"cholera","PatientName":"Michael","PatientResidenceArea":"Muhokya","Latitude":0.3249832,"Longitude":32.5753133,"HealthFacilityName":"Mulago"}])`.  Is that the correct syntax for JSON

Comment: Now  i used this logic to concatenate , but still not showing :  `var URL = 'http://192.168.0.6:72/Mobile/Fetch.aspx?DataFormat=Details';
            var a_url = 'qfeed_callback({' + URL + '})';
            script.src = ''+a_url;`

Comment: Concatenating the function name on the URL will not work. You have to change Fetch.aspx so that it returns the JSON array inside a script, like this: `eqfeed_callback([{"Id":1,"Country":"Uganda","District":"kamp‌​ala","SubCounty":"Hi‌​ma","EpidemicName":"‌​cholera","PatientNam‌​e":"Michael","Patien‌​tResidenceArea":"Muh‌​okya","Latitude":0.3‌​249832,"Longitude":3‌​2.5753133,"HealthFac‌​ilityName":"Mulago"}‌​])` instead of only returning the JSON array.

Comment: I know this might be a short cut how can i just concatenate it on the Json string which has just come @JasonSmith please . Thanks

Comment: If you can't change the aspx page, then you must use an AJAX library like jQuery. In jQuery, you could say `$.getJSON('http://192.168.0.6:72/Mobile/Fetch.aspx?DataFormat=Details', eqfeed_callback);` Of course you have to load jQuery first.

Comment: Finally it worked i had no Option rather , changing my JSON structure as you suggested